# Tile/live tile change color when windows change theme UWP

Tags: colors, win-universal-app, tile

In my UWP application in tile I set black color of background, and icon has transperent background, it's look very well. But then i change theme in windows 10(desktop) to white and my tile change background color to white. Why is it happend, when i set color - black in manifest of application. Like in this application.

[image]

Best regards, Dmitry

Comment: By changing the theme in windows 10 (desktop) to white, do you mean changing the theme to high contrast white?

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment but if you mean the high contrast setting I do not believe this is possible since the tile settings cannot be changed at runtime and there is no other way to set the color outside of the apps manifest. You can create override the styles for other controls but not for the tiles properties.

"Note  It’s possible to override the system color resources for high-contrast color and accent color by creating resources with the same names, but it’s a best practice to respect the user’s color choices, especially for high-contrast settings. [Xaml Theme Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources)
More on high contrast themes here: [High Contrast Themes - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/accessibility/high-contrast-themes)

I would instead try setting the image background to not be transparent and take up the whole space of the tile. You won't be able to change it but it appears you want it always black anyways. I am not certain this will work in your scenario though since you are using a live tile and not just an image.

You may also want to look at using a secondary tile: [Theme Resources](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/806ae039-5a64-443e-ba52-458e324e6024/uwpvbc-change-application-visualelements-backgroundcolor?forum=wpdevelop)